# Visual Studio MVC Copy Paste Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

How do I copy paste a `ASP.NET MVC` project from Visual Studio? I have an assignment to submit the project to the lecturer, however they request to copy paste the whole project to an external drive. The problem is when I copy paste the project to a removable disk, it can't run properly with loads of errors. How do I do this in the cleanest way possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy and paste the whole project folder not just the project file. 
When you first fully save everything (or exit and choose to save) the project files will be saved in the expected location.

You can change default folder for new projects in Visual Studio settings.

1. Click Tools menu
2. Click Options
3. Find "Projects and Solutions"
4. Choose "Project location"
   AppData folder is hidden. You have to type its address in address bar manually or you can enable view for hidden files in Windows Explorer.